# Configure Azure AD Connect Cloud Sync without Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to reproduce the steps to "Configure Azure AD Connect cloud sync" from the Azure portal, in another way using an API?

The steps are described at this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/tutorial-single-forest#configure-azure-ad-connect-cloud-sync

I would like to automate this process to have no user interaction. Is it possible with the Graph API? Any example?

Comment: Yes you can programmatically configure Azure AD Connect Cloud sync. You can refer to the steps in "How to programmatically configure cloud sync using MS Graph API": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/how-to-inbound-synch-ms-graph

 Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you Marilee! I am trying to follow this document but this is very difficult to understand. I managed to call the first command " Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled -EnableDirSync $true" but I can't get past the next one. I don't understand this sentence: "You need to use this application ID 1a4721b3-e57f-4451-ae87-ef078703ec94. The displayName is the AD domain url, if used in the portal (for example, contoso.com), but it may be named something else."

What is the application id I should use? And what is the display name? I get 401 or 403 errors. Is there an additional step before this?

Comment: You have to use the same application id that is provided there (1a4721b3-e57f-4451-ae87-ef078703ec94) but you can use any display name as per your convenience. could you tell from where you are doing the post from ? if you are using graph explorer then make sure you have the required permissions . please refer: https://i.imgur.com/aihhHzy.png after this you will get the service principal id which can be used for further steps mentioned in the documentation shared by Marilee Turscak -MSFT.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the screenshot! I managed to call this method and get a result.

Comment: Glad to hear that .. will post it as answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Marilee Turscak - MSFT for providing the reference Link.

> I don't understand this sentence: "You need to use this application
> ID 1a4721b3-e57f-4451-ae87-ef078703ec94. The displayName is the AD
> domain url, if used in the portal (for example, contoso.com), but it
> may be named something else." What is the application id I should use?
> And what is the display name? I get 401 or 403 errors. Is there an
> additional step before this?

You have to use the same application ID as its the Application templateID by default which is used to provision entries from active directory to Azure active directory.

[image]

But You can use any Display name that you want and Please make sure to have the required permissions as shown below. You can perform the post operation with Graph explorer.

[image]

After you have done the above post operation you will get the service principal ID which can be used for further steps mentioned in the document provided by [Marilee Turscak - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9541448/marilee-turscak-msft).

**Reference:**

[How to programmatically configure cloud sync using MS Graph API | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/how-to-inbound-synch-ms-graph)

Comment: This is awesome! Kudos for explaining what "1a4721b3-e57f-4451-ae87-ef078703ec94" actually is